# How i can static build GDB from source?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

I've download gdb-6.5.bz2.tar. Untar this file.
I write:
LDFLAGS=-static 
./configure

but as a result i get a gdb, which require a so files, for instance: ncurses.so.5 libc.so.0 etc

How i can build statically ?

Comment: You probably can't.  If you want to, you'll have to get static versions of all the prerequisite libraries, which is probably more recompilation than is worth your while.  Why do you want to build a statically linked GDB?  The dynamically linked version will be much simpler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If you want to debug a newly-bootstrapped system, static-linked gdb is extremely valuable. This is even more true if the new system will be using an incompatible ABI from the original system you're building on -- for example, a different libc or a different default calling convention.

Comment: @R..: fine, but then you'll need to obtain or build a static library for each and every library that GDB links with.  On a RHEL 5 system, that means: libreadline.so.5, libncurses.so.5, libm.so.6, libexpat.so.0, libdl.so.2, libc.so.6, /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 if the output of `ldd /usr/bin/gdb` is to be trusted.  I'm not sure whether you'd really want to replace all those with static libraries, but that's the list of shared libraries used by `gdb` on this (antique) platform.

Comment: That's just glibc, readline, ncurses, and expat - 4 libraries. libdl, libc, ld-linux, and libm are all part of glibc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This message](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/gdb/1999-q3/msg00331.html) seems to imply that the correct usage is

```
$ make LDFLAGS=-static
```

Which seems surprising. Unfortunately, it also says it fails to build, and there are no follow-ups. Still the message is from 1999 so everything might have changed, perhaps the proper way today is to do it your way.

Comment: This works for me!

Comment: What version of gdb were you able to build this way @Changbin Du, and what distro/version did you compile from?

Answer (score 9):

Both gcc and gdb disrespect the `--enable-static` flag which should be passed to `configure`, the correct way to do this is:

In the case of gdb 8.0, you have to also add the `--disable-interprocess-agent` to successfully build a static version:

`mkdir build-gdb && cd build-gdb && ../configure --prefix=... --enable-static --disable-interprocess-agent ...`

In the case of gcc 7.1, you have to also add the `--disable-libcc1` to successfully build a static version:

`mkdir build-gcc && cd build-gcc && ../configure --prefix=... --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-libcc1 ...`

Comment: I'm curious how you found these options. The documentations did not mention these.

Comment: I build with --enable-static=yes, but the output is still dynamically linked.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following options for *configure* script to generate a static GDB executable:

```
./configure --prefix=<> --enable-static=yes && make && make install
```