# Android: building a static aarch64 gdb

Tags: android, gdb

I am having a lot of trouble using gdbserver and gdbserver64 on Android and the companion aarch64 gdb on my host. For example, I run into issues like this, where gdb is outputting what seems to be nonsense:

```
(gdb) target remote :5039
Remote debugging using :5039
warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
try using the "file" command first.
0x0000007fa7921d2c in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb.frames: 
#0  0x0000007fa7921d2c in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000040000600 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x22eee199476794f4
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007f87c249b4 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/4i $pc
=> 0x7f87c249b4:    ldrb    w8, [x0,#432]
   0x7f87c249b8:    cbz w8, 0x7f87c249ec
   0x7f87c249bc:    ldr x8, [x19,#3632]
   0x7f87c249c0:    ldr x9, [x8,#24]
(gdb) bt
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb.frames: 
#0  0x0000007f87c249b4 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000007fa4b4fb25 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 22374]
[New Thread 22375]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007f87c249b4 in ?? ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007f87c249b4 in ?? ()
```

This is almost impossible to use, with everything being totally unhelpful. No symbols are loaded and no backtraces are even remotely reasonable. The app is also repeatedly signaled in places that it is not signaled at when being straced or traced using a static gdb (just to name one specific problem with it).

However, I was able to use a prebuilt armv7a *statically linked* gdb binary to debug some 32-bit applications in an Android emulator with relative ease. I ran the static gdb in a device shell without issue. I had no trouble loading symbols and had no odd signaling problems.

I couldn't find a statically linked aarch64 gdb binary anywhere, so I tried to build one inside my aarch64 chroot. I did manage to build gdb for aarch64, and I used [these configure flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763263/10363793):

```
LDFLAGS="-static" ../configure --prefix=/noprefix --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-interprocess-agent --disable-libcc1
```

But it is dynamically linked, which is not what I wanted.

```
root@gram:/opt/gdb-aarch64/noprefix/bin# file gdb
gdb: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=f1a630e569467794c45b4389f510720c4342704b, not stripped
```

How do I build a statically linked linux aarch64 gdb?